# Juntar varios valores do tipo IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Estou a receber da minha View um array de valores com os dias da semana.
Domingo,Segunda-Feira,etc.
Quero comparar esse array com um atributo do tipo string da minha base de dados e guardar numa variável do tipo "IQueryable". E ir somando os conteúdos das tabelas.
Mas o C# não me deixa somar essa variável.

```
public JsonResult GetCatequizandosByDiasDisponiveis(string[] diasPertendidos, string anoCatequese)
{
    var catequizandosPorDiasDisponiveis = (from i in db.Inscricao
                                           join c in db.Catequizando on i.CatequizandoID equals c.CatequizandoID
                                           join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequizandoID equals p.PessoaID
                                           where  i.AnoCatequese == anoCatequese
                                           select new {
                                               PessoaID = p.PessoaID,
                                               Nome = p.Nome,
                                               Dispo = i.Dias_Preferencial
                                           });

    foreach (string dia in diasPertendidos ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
    {
        // para cada 'dia' ver quais os catequizandos possiveis <--- catequizandosPorDiasDisponiveis
        // depois, juntar tudo e eliminar os repetidos
        catequizandosPorDiasDisponiveis += catequizandosPorDiasDisponiveis.Where(d => d.Dispo.Contains(dia));
    }

    return Json(catequizandosPorDiasDisponiveis, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

O meu problemas está aqui:

> catequizandosPorDiasDisponiveis +=
>   catequizandosPorDiasDisponiveis.Where(d => d.Dispo.Contains(dia));

Answer (score 0):

voçê não precisa do `+=`, o método `Where()` já retorna um `IQueryable`.

```
catequizandosPorDiasDisponiveis = catequizandosPorDiasDisponiveis.Where(d => d.Dispo.Contains(dia));
```

em todo caso, este loop adicionando um where com contains me preocupa um pouco. talvez seja melhor você fazer um join com diasPertendidos, então você poderia tentar algo do genero:

```
from i in db.Inscricao
join c in db.Catequizando on i.CatequizandoID equals c.CatequizandoID
join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequizandoID equals p.PessoaID
join d in diasPertendidos on 1 == 1
where 
    i.AnoCatequese == anoCatequese &&
    i.Dias_Preferencial.All(x => d)
select new {
   PessoaID = p.PessoaID,
   Nome = p.Nome,
   Dispo = i.Dias_Preferencial
}
```

caso queira que `Dias_Preferencial` possua todos os dias passados em `diasPertendidos`, então use a negação do método `Except` com `Any`.

```
from i in db.Inscricao
join c in db.Catequizando on i.CatequizandoID equals c.CatequizandoID
join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequizandoID equals p.PessoaID
where 
    i.AnoCatequese == anoCatequese &&
    !diasPertendidos.Except(i.Dias_Preferencial).Any()
select new {
   PessoaID = p.PessoaID,
   Nome = p.Nome,
   Dispo = i.Dias_Preferencial
}
```

Comment: O já tinha feito um join ao meu array, mas assim devolve todas as pessoas que tivessem escolhido "Domingo E Segunda" e não "Domingo OU Segunda". Por isso estava a tentar fazer um contador dentro do meu foreach Não sei se estou a ser explicito.

Comment: @SimãoLopes faça um group by pelo dia.

Comment: Dentro do foreach ?

Comment: Não resulta alguma forma de incrementar variáveis do tipo _IQueryable_?

Comment: Simão, pelo o que entendi, na sua Entidade `Inscrito`, você tem uma propriedade `Dias_Preferencial` que é uma `List<String>` com as datas, tipo `["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça"]` e o array `diasPertendidos` é uma lista semelhante... você quer que `Inscrito.Dias_Preferencial` possua todos os valores de `diasPertendidos` ou pelo menos um valor?

Comment: Pelo menos um valor.

Comment: Fiz    "string convertestringdias = string.Join(",", diasPertendidos);" ,   "!diasPertendidos.Except(i.Dias_Preferencial).Any()", e não me devolve dados